# Django: Custom LoginView is not authenticating users

Tags: python, django

I've made a custom LoginView, only to pass some context variables.

But now when I do login, users don't login only redirect to page indicated in the `urls.py` file:

```
from core import views

app_name = "core"

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.ScolarteHome.as_view(), name='home'),
        path("ingresar/", views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='scolarte/registration/login.html', success_url=reverse_lazy('core:home')), name="login"),
    ]
```

My Custom LoginView:

```
class LoginView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, FormView):
    """
    Display the login form and handle the login action.
    """
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        msg = {'cliente': 'Ingresar como cliente', 'vendedor': 'Ingresar como vendedor'}
        context['msg'] = msg.get(self.request.GET.get('cliente-o-vendedor'), '')
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span2','placeholder': 'Nombre de usuario'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'span2','placeholder':'Contraseña'}))
```

Comment: Have you set the `LOGIN_URL` variable in your settings.py file?

Comment: @Daniel, yes: `LOGIN_URL = 'core:login'` is that ok?

Comment: My apologies, I meant the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, variable which is responsible for redirecting users upon authentication. Something like this: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'` - here users get redirected to the profile page when they log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `FormView` which doesn't provide authentication logic, you can use `LoginView` as parent class directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    """
    Display the login form and handle the login action.
    """
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        msg = {'cliente': 'Ingresar como cliente', 'vendedor': 'Ingresar como vendedor'}
        context['msg'] = msg.get(self.request.GET.get('cliente-o-vendedor'), '')
        return context
```